# Protovis jQuery tipsy doesn't work with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, tipsy, protovis

I have tipsy working fine on my chart. The `mouseover` event worked fine but when I added a `click` event, it doesn't execute the `click` event as I wanted.

Below is my code:

```
var vis = new pv.Panel()
            .width(w)
            .height(h);

            vis.add(pv.Bar)
            .data(data)
            .width(4)
            .left(function() 5 * this.index)
            .height(function(d) Math.round(d*4))
            .bottom(0)
            .text(function(d) d.toFixed(1))
            .event("mouseover", pv.Behavior.tipsy({gravity: "w", fade: true}))
            //If I remove the mouseover event, the click event will work but not when both are veing put together.
            .event("click", function() self.location = "http://stanford.edu");

            vis.render();
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

here's a workaround. you can pass in a click callback function into pv.Behavior.tipsy and call the click event within it.

1. modify pv.Behavior.tipsy(...) to pass in a callback function:

   pv.Behavior.tipsy = function(opts, callback)
2. modify event call to pass in a callback funciton:

   .event("mouseover", pv.Behavior.tipsy({gravity: "w", fade: true}, function(){alert('click call back');}))
3. modify the last line in return function in protovis.tipsy.js:

   return function(d) {
         .......
          $(tip).mouseleave(cleanup).tipsy("show");
          if(callback) {
               $(tip).click(callback);
             }
           };

Comment: Excellent, this worked for me when I ran into the same issue.